# replacing image paths in minified css with sed

Tags: css, image, sed, minify

I am concatenating all the css files and minifying them and putting it in a dist directory for distribution. The css files I am concatenating are in various vendor folders and have image paths relative to that css in them. How can I replace all the image paths with the relative images directory in the distributable using sed?

Some possible paths to the images in the css...

```
background-image: url('test/test1/test.png');
background: url("test2/test2.png");
background-image: url(test3/test3.png);
background: url ( test4/test4.png );
background: url( " test5/test5.gif");
background: url(test.png);
```

Comment: I have tried sed "s|url\(.*?.png\)|url(\1)|g" style.css ... but that ofcourse does not work.

Comment: Is what you posted sample input or expected output or something else? Update your question to clearly show representative sample input plus the expected output from that input.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Works for all your examples.

```
sed "s#\(url\s*(\s*['\"]\?\)\s*\([^/]\)#\1/DIRECTORY/\2#" <in.css >out.css
```

Which translated means

q1: "url"-optional spaces-"("-optional spaces-optional quote

q2: optional spaces

q3: any character apart from a "/" (to avoid replacing absolute urls)

Then if all those match, replace with q1-"/DIRECTORY/"-q3